# Dreamweaver Connect to site via HTTP

Tags: http, connection, webserver, expression, dreamweaver

In Microsoft Expression 2003, I am able to connect to my client's website using the "HTTP" method provided in their program.

In Expression, the only three values I need to connect and access the files is the website domain, username, and password. However, this is the only way I've been able to connect to their server.

I normally use Adobe Dreamweaver for working on websites.

Is there an Adobe Dreamweaver equivalent for Expression's HTTP connection?

Thanks for any help.

P.S. The website is running on an IIS server if that is important.

Comment: I hope my answer given below will help you a lot.

Comment: Do you have acces to the server? i mean is it your own?

Comment: No, I have no access to anything but the website. I don't need instruction on how to set up anything. I just want guidance on how to connect to the server via Dreamweaver, as MS-Expression does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [**Dreamweaver Help / Connect to a remote server**](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/connect-remote-server.html)

Once you’ve specified a local site in Dreamweaver, you can specify a remote server for your site as well. The remote server (often referred to as the web server) is where you publish your site files so that people can view them online. The remote server is simply another computer like your local computer with a collection of files and folders on it. You’ll specify a folder for your site on the remote server, just as you specified a folder for your local site on your local computer.

Dreamweaver refers to the specified remote folder as your remote site.

When you set up a remote folder, you must select a connection method for Dreamweaver to upload and download files to and from your web server. The most typical connection method is FTP, but Dreamweaver also supports local/network, FTPS, SFTP, WebDav, and RDS connection methods. If you don’t know which connection method to use, ask your ISP or your server administrator.

> Note:
>   Dreamweaver also supports connections to IPv6-enabled servers. Supported connection types include FTP, SFTP, WebDav, and RDS. For more information, see www.ipv6.org/

### Specify a connection method

**WebDAV connections:**

Use this setting if you connect to your web server using the Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV) protocol.

For this connection method, you must have a server that supports this protocol, such as Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS) 5.0 or an appropriately configured installation of Apache web server.

**RDS connections:**

Use this setting if you connect to your web server using Remote Development Services (RDS). For this connection method, your remote server must be on a computer running Adobe® ColdFusion®

Comment: Yes yes, I know all this - I wanted to know specifics. I've tried WebDav and it never connects. I use the same information that I use in MS-Expression but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV connection is your way to go if you just want to use Dreamweaver and fill in the Host, username and password. However WebDav works perfectly fine on a Linux apache environment, But installing it on IIS is a bit harder.

[image: WebDAV]

*Take a look at [this website](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis/) explaining step by step how to install and configure WebDAV correctly on IIS before using it.*